# vftpd issue regarding file permissions and user rights

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

My system is:
Ubuntu 10.04 / Apache2

The question is related to the sofware vftpd - an ftp server for linux (https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html)

I have installed vftpd and it works fine. I am having an issue though trying to understand why  users are able to delete files which are owned by root. I have set up the ftp server with the option "local_enable=YES" and also "chroot_local_user=YES" so that the users cannot navigate outside their home directory.

The strange thing is that if a file is owned by root, the ftp users are able to delete it. Is a user able to delete any file in the home directory regardless of who owns it?

I want to prevent users from being able to delete files, or allow other users to only have read access to the home directories of other users.

If anyone knows the vftpd software and can help i´d be most grateful,

yours,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked which is the chmod of the files? If all files belongs to the same group, and the group have read and write privileges, any user can modify the files through ftp.

Comment: Hi,the file belongs to root:root but the directory belongs to the ftp user. I gather then, that if a directory is owned by the ftp user he can also delete all files inside although they may not belong to him. Thanks, Rob